# How to alter a snowflake table to drop a field in VARIANT data type?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant, alter

I have a snowflake table with a VARIANT column. Can I alter my table to drop one of the fields in Variant column?

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME
        DROP COLUMN VARIANTDATA:FIELDNAME;
```

It gave me syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Anything a VARIANT column contains is considered a value just as any structured column. And you cannot drop a column value/Data using DDL statement.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#variant